# glassfish v3 asadmin how to specify XA on connection factory

Tags: jms, glassfish-3, xa

This worked in GFV2:

$AS_HOME/bin/asadmin \
    --host $AS_ADMIN_HOST \
    --user $AS_ADMIN_USER \
    --port $AS_ADMIN_PORT \
    create-jms-resource \
    --restype javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory \
    --description XA\ Queue\ Connection\ Factory \
    --property Name=myXAQueueConnectionFactory:SupportsXA=true \
    jms/myXAQueueConnectionFactory

But the SupportsXA=true no longer works. Maybe I can't find it in the GFV3 manuals, nor can I find it via our friend Google: how to specify XA transactionality using asadmin to configure the factory? Anybody out there know how?

Answer (score 1):

--property ...:transaction-support=XATransaction:...

This seems to be what I needed. Works. Did not find by search of documentation or by Google. Deduced it by looking at the domain.xml file and taking educated guess at syntax.

Am now trying to figure out what property name/value pair sets the connection-validation property the way I want it.

Question has morphed to: what's the full asadmin syntax and property setting for GFV3 connection factories.